# Intel WiFi Link 5100 on Budgie 19.10

Tags: networking, 19.10, iwlwifi, budgie

I am coming from a Linux Mint environment and I have recently installed Ubuntu Budgie 19.10 on my Dell e6400 laptop. My wireless card has worked in the past with no issues on Linux Mint. However, since installing Budgie 19.10 (previous version does not work either), the wireless card can see my 2.4 Ghz network, however, when authenticating it times out and asks for the passcode again. Connecting on the 5Ghz side has no issues.

The installed wireless card is an Intel WiFi Link 5100. Wireless card details:

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: WiFi Link 5100
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: wlp12s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:22:fb:1d:15:60
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-26-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 ip=192.168.0.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:28 memory:f69fe000-f69fffff
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks, Dubya

Comment: Have you rebooted the router? Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `uname -a`. Is the same password used for 2.4 and 5ghz networks?

Comment: the result for uname - Linux dubya-Latitude-E6400 5.3.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 05:37:46 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. The password for both networks are the same. How do I run dkms to produce the result you are seeking? Sorry I am not proficient with Linux yet

Comment: forgot to mention. I just rebooted the router before running uname

Comment: Did rebooting the router help at all? Do you have WPA2 encryption set in both the computer and the router? Are all of your software updates done? `dkms status` is the complete command that I'm looking for. Also, edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. Had personal matters to deal with.

Rebooting the router did not resolve the issue. Yes, WPA2 is enabled on both. Both frequencies share the same network name with the frequency tagged to the name. Both frequencies share the same password. All software updates had been performed.

I cannot locate the Interfaces folder under Network. In the Network folder are four sub folders:
if-down.d
if-post-down.d
if-pre-up.d 
if-up.d

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml produces:

(the hastag was removed to prevent the remainder of the text to go into bold and larger font) Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

When I perform the dkms command nothing happens (please go easy on me I am a linux noob)

Thank you,

Dubya

Comment: I just booted Ubuntu 18.04 64bit from a bootable USB and tested the wifi. Both 2.4 and 5Ghz worked first time. WPA 2 enabled.  Hope this helps.